# Identifying accessors and mutators (getters/setters) of all IMethods of an IType

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I can access all methods of an `IType` with the method `getMethods()`. Is there an efficient way to determine if such an `IMethod` is an accessor or a mutator (getter/setter)?

Checking if the name of an `IMethod` matches the scheme `prefix + NameOfAttribute` with `prefix ∈ {"get", "set", "is"}` would help me to detect the obvious ones, but if an accessor or a mutator (getter/setter) is not named that way, it would not work.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**: I only want to identify getter/setter methods that directly get/set an attribute of the `IType` and do not do anything else.

**EDIT2**: Used technical terms: accessor & mutator

**EDIT3**: Here is my **solution** after reading all the answers:

```
    private boolean isAccessor(IMethod method) throws JavaModelException {
        if (isAccessMethod("get", method) || isAccessMethod("is", method)) { // if name fits
            return method.getNumberOfParameters() == 0 && !Signature.SIG_VOID.equals(method.getReturnType());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isMutator(IMethod method) throws JavaModelException {
        if (isAccessMethod("set", method)) { // if name fits
            return method.getNumberOfParameters() == 1 && Signature.SIG_VOID.equals(method.getReturnType());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isAccessMethod(String prefix, IMethod method) throws JavaModelException {
        IType type = method.getDeclaringType();
        for (IField field : type.getFields()) { // for ever field of IType:
            if (method.getElementName().equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + field.getElementName())) {
                return true; // is access method if name scheme fits for one field
            }
        }
        return false; // is not an access method if no field fits
    }
```

**IMPORTANT: This solution fits my requirements, but ignores some important cases (see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740704/6634600))**. This still does not check the functionality of the method, but it works pretty well. It checks the method name for the scheme I proposed. But it also checks the parameter count and whether the return type is `void` or not. If someone wanted to improve this he could also check whether the return/parameter type of the getter matches to the type of the field that was matched to the method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that there is no support for identifying getters and setters in the JDT core.

There is only a public API in the JDT that provides getter/setter names generation based on field names. E.g. [`NamingConvention`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FNamingConventions.html) Take a look at the [`suggestGetterName()`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/NamingConventions.html#suggestGetterName-org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject-char:A-int-boolean-char:A:A-) method.

Other internal classes like `GetterSetterUtil` also do not provide the method you want.

Finally I would create a property accessor detector by myself. Maybe as a filter that I can apply on `Collection`s.

> Checking if the name of an IMethod matches the scheme prefix + NameOfAttribute with prefix ∈ {"get", "set"}

Also check the `is` prefix in case of a boolean property and the parameter list of the method. Getters usually don't take parameters while setters usually take one parameter. I said usually, because the [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) also allows indexed properties. E.g.

```
 void setter(int index, PropertyType value); // indexed setter
 PropertyType getter(int index); // indexed getter
 void setter(PropertyType values[]); // array setter
 PropertyType[] getter(); // array getter
```

**EDIT**

> I added my own solution based on your proposals to my post.

Your solution might fit your requirements. Just keep in mind that a property might not have a direct backing-field. The concept of a property is a bit more abstract. I mean that if you have a property named `visible` and a getter `isVisible()` the class might not have a field `private boolean visible`.

To make it clear you should take a look at the property `rootPane` from `JComponent`. It is definitely a property, because the [`Introspector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) returns it.

```
BeanInfo jcomponentBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(JComponent.class);

PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = jcomponentBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptors.length; i++) {
  PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = propertyDescriptors[i];
  if("rootPane".equals(propertyDescriptor.getName())){
    System.out.println("Found property rootPane");
    break;
  }
}
```

will print out

```
Found property rootPane
```

But it don't uses a direct backing-field if you take a look at the implementation.

```
public JRootPane getRootPane() {
    return SwingUtilities.getRootPane(this);
}
```

and `SwingUtilities.getRootPane`

```
public static JRootPane getRootPane(Component c) {
    if (c instanceof RootPaneContainer) {
        return ((RootPaneContainer)c).getRootPane();
    }
    for( ; c != null; c = c.getParent()) {
        if (c instanceof JRootPane) {
            return (JRootPane)c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I just want to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the is prefix, I would have forgot that! Also, the parameter count is a good idea.

Comment: I added my own solution based on your proposals to my post.

Comment: Thanks for your update. This is an interesting example, which makes it even harder to identify precisely accessors and mutators. My solution might fit my requirements, but is no universal solution for the problem. I will add that as a disclaimer to my post.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

```
for (IMethod m : iType.getMethods()) {
    if (m.getElementName().substring(0,3).equals("get")) {
        //do something
    } else if (m.getElementName().substring(0,3).equals("set")) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

You can use `getFields()` on a `IType` and then `getElementName()` for each field.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I proposed in my question. The problem is that if the method is not a getter but is named `getXYZ()`, it will wrongfully be declared as a getter.

Comment: You can get an array of declared fields by calling `getFields()`.
Then use a for each loop... `for (Field field : iType.getFields())`.

Comment: Yeah but this still only checks the name of the method. This would be an ok solution, but maybe there is a way to check the functionality of the method with the JDT API.